# CLAMAV hangs while reading database

Tags: clamav

I restart clamav and review logs and see this

```
Mon Jan 11 11:14:49 2010 -> +++ Started at Mon Jan 11 11:14:49 2010
Mon Jan 11 11:14:49 2010 -> clamd daemon 0.90.1 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: i386, CPU: i486)
Mon Jan 11 11:14:49 2010 -> Log file size limit disabled.
Mon Jan 11 11:14:49 2010 -> Reading databases from /var/lib/clamav
```

seems that clamav don't finish read the database. There are othe log entries and it seems reading the database needs up to 6 hours (!). Also clamav takes most CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known problem with clamav old versions, try to update clamav to latest version ( 0.95.3 )

Quote from clamav.net

> All ClamAV releases older than 0.95 are affected by a bug in freshclam which prevents incremental updates from working with signatures longer than 980 bytes.